# Remote Debugging Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I want to debug a java application running on remote server using Eclipse. I know that there is option for creating a remote debugging configuration in eclipse: `Debug Configurations -> Remote Java Application`.

But my problem is that what should I put in the "Host" field. I don't have a direct connection with the server but through a contact server. For e.g. I have contact server : `abc@contact.xyz.com` , I login into contact server and then log into my sever using:  `ssh server1`, so my application is running on server1. I cannot directly access server1 but only after logging into contact server.

So what should I fill in Host field in my case?

Comment: if you are using linux then your eclipse is actually using gdb, and you can run gdb the same way you run ssh.. (console) what is the problem then?

Answer (score 2):

Try use portforwarding, for example with putty if you have a windows machine:
http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

For mac try this (didn't try it myself because i lack a mac ;-))
http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/05/how-to-ssh-port-forwarding-on-mac-osx.html

Comment: Unfortunately I have a mac machine and server is linux